# Is there a way to use the Locate database to perform a copy in Unix Shell?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, locate

From a Unix shell.

I want to find a file specifically using `locate <filename>` and then I want to copy the files that were located using `cp`. I've tried something like:

`Locate  -name "*.doc" -exec cp {} /path/to/copy/to`

Comment: Putty is irrelevant. Using the shell is the same no matter how you connect.

Comment: You need to put `\;` at the end of the `-exec` parameters.

Comment: `locate` is all lowercase. Very few Unix commands have uppercase letters in the name.

Comment: Your arguments are for `find`, not `locate`.

Comment: `find . -name "*.doc" -exec cp {} /path/to/copy/to \;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221841/discussion-between-lea-gris-and-barmar).

Comment: @LéaGris I didn't close it. I cast the first vote, it wasn't closed until 2 more people voted. This is on the wrong site.

Comment: what about xargs: `locate  .doc | xargs -I{} cp {} /path/to/copy/to`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to perform actions with files-path found by the locate database, the `locate` command has no `-exec` option to execute a command on located files (`-exec` exist for the `find` command).

If working with the Locate database's `locate` command:

1. You probably want to locate from the base name rather than the whole path; so use `-b '*.doc'`.
2. You want the pattern inside single quotes so it is not expanded by the current shell interpreter, but only by the `locate` command.
3. You want the located files to actually exist so use the `-e` switch.
4. You want a `null` delimited list of entries, so it is safe to iterate paths, even if it contains non-printable special characters, spaces, newlines, tabs…
5. Since `locate` has no direct mean to execute a command with arguments, you will pipe the output stream into `xargs` to do it instead.

```sh
locate -0eb '*.doc' |
  xargs -0 \
    sh -c 'cp -- "$@" /path/to/copy/to/' _
```

Explanations:

- `locate -0eb '*.doc'`: Using the locate database; locate files that still exist right-now having the base name matching the `*.doc` pattern, and output the list as a `null` delimited list of paths.
- `| xargs -0`: Pipe the `null` delimited list of paths to `xargs` to pass the entries as argument to the following command.
- `sh -c`: Execute the inline shell script that follow.
- `cp -- "$@" /path/to/copy/to/'`: The inline shell script that copy all received paths as arguments array `$@` into `/path/to/copy/to/`.

Finally note some key differences between `locate` and `find`:

- `locate` uses a database to reference files within the system. There is a programmed `cron` job, to update the Locate database (usually once a day, calling the `/etc/cron.daily/mlocate` script for example). `locate` is fast because of that, but it also cannot find recent files until it has updated its database.
- `find` directly accesses the filesystem. It traverses directories recursively and identify files/paths endpoint types. It also has more options and capabilities like passing paths as arguments and execute commands.

For further reading, see: [SuperUser.com: What is the difference between 'locate' and 'find' in Linux?](https://superuser.com/questions/199472/what-is-the-difference-between-locate-and-find-in-linux)

Comment: I appreciate you response and explanation. I tried this and receive the following error

Comment: @yakshpatel error code is missing. Although the `locate` or the `xargs` command available to your system may differs by options, especially those available for MacOS. You may need to adapt my answer after reading the man-pages for `locate` and `xargs` available with your system.